Calculate $\sum\limits_{1\leq i \leq j \leq 2n-1} \dfrac{1}{(2+\epsilon_i) (2+ \epsilon_j)}$
Problem: Let $\epsilon_0 =1, \epsilon_1, \ldots, \epsilon_{2n-1}$ be the $(2n-1)^{th}-$roots of  $1$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Calculate the following sum $$\sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq j \leq 2n-1} \dfrac{1}{(2+\epsilon_i) (2+ \epsilon_j)}.$$
Comments: In fact, I split this sum into $2$ parts. The first part, $i= j$ and second part $i< j$.  Then the sum can rewrite to
$\sum\limits_{1\leq i \leq 2n-1} \dfrac{1}{(2+\epsilon_i)^2} + \sum\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq 2n-1} \dfrac{1}{(2+\epsilon_i) (2+ \epsilon_j)}$.
I showed that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n-1} \epsilon_i = 0$.
The question is how to calculate the above sums?
Thank you so much for all your hints!

looks like your sum is just $\left(\sum_j\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_j}\right)^2$ to begin with

I think the sum $\sum_{j}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_j}$ can be computed by using the logarithmic derivative $f'(z)/f(z)$, where $f(z)=\prod_{j}(z-\varepsilon_j)=z^{2n-1}+\ldots+z+1$. Perhaps you can further differentiate it in $z$ and evaluate at $z=-2$ to get an answer.

@richrow Oh, this is an important hint. The function f(x) is nice.  Thank you so much!

For an easier (to me) approach, find the change of variables $ y = \frac{ 1}{2+x}$, and then use Vieta's for $ \sum y_i y_j$.

@dezdichado No it's not. You're referring to summing over $ 1 \leq i, j \leq 2n-1$. Here, the cross terms have a coefficient of 1.

@dezdichado Ah, thank you. But, the sum is only over $1 \leq i \leq j \leq 2n-1$. However, from the hints of richrow I saw a solution to my problem.

Let's switch to $2n+1$ in notation (with $n\in\mathsf{Z}^{+}\cup\left\{ 0\right\}$ as $0\in\mathsf{N}$ is ambiguous)
$x^{2n+1}-1=0$ has complex roots $\varepsilon_{i}$, so $\left(x-2\right)^{2n+1}-1=0$'s
roots are $2+\varepsilon_{i}$, therefore the roots of $x^{2n+1}\left[\left(\frac{1}{x}-2\right)^{2n+1}-1\right]=0$
are exaclty $\delta_{i}=\left(2+\varepsilon_{i}\right)^{-1}$ in $\mathsf{C}$, as $2+\varepsilon_i\neq0$
Now expand this polynomial:
$$
x^{2n+1}\left[\left(\frac{1}{x}-2\right)^{2n+1}-1\right]=\left[\left(1-2x\right)^{2n+1}-x^{2n+1}\right]=-x^{2n+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{2n+1}\left(-1\right)^{j}2^{j}x^{j}\binom{2n+1}{j}=
$$
$$
=-\left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)x^{2n+1}+2n\cdot2^{2n}x^{2n}-2^{2n-1}x^{2n-1}n\left(2n+1\right)+\ldots
$$
So by Viete:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}=-\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+1}}=\frac{2n\cdot2^{2n}}{\left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)}
$$
$$
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\cdot\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{i}}=\frac{a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n+1}}=\frac{2^{2n-1}n\left(2n+1\right)}{\left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)}
$$
Recall the elementary symmetric polynomials:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\right)^{2}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\right)^{2}-2\left(\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\cdot\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{i}}\right)
$$
Therefore:
$$
\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\cdot\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{i}}=\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\right)^{2}+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\cdot\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{i}}=$$
$$=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\right)^{2}-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq2n+1}\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{j}}\cdot\frac{1}{2+\varepsilon_{i}}=
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{2n\cdot2^{2n}}{\left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)}\right)^{2}-\frac{2^{2n-1}n\left(2n+1\right)}{\left(2^{2n+1}+1\right)}
$$

Thank you, this is nice solution!
